# Shell script zenity - check if canceled

Tags: bash, shell

I wish to break while loop, that keep asking me for password using zenity, when user click cancel in password dialog...otherwise program should keep asking for password.

This is my first problem, but second one is, that even if I enter good password at the while loop is keep running and keep asking me for password.

```
VAR_PASS = $(zenity --password)
while ! $VAR_PASS | sudo -S echo ''; do
    VAR_PASS=$(zenity --password)
    #check if cancel button pressed, then return
done
```

Comment: Aside from your other problems, you need to remove those spaces around `=`.

Comment: @devnull is right: variable assignment looks like `var=value` -- bash is very sensitive to whitespace: spaces separate words into commands  and arguments

Comment: thanks, I repaired that, but still the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
VAR_PASS=""
while [[ -z $VAR_PASS ]] || ! sudo -S echo <<< "$VAR_PASS"; do
    VAR_PASS=$(zenity --password)
    if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
        #  cancel button pressed
    elif [[ $? -eq 5 ]]; then
        #  timeout
    fi
done
```

Comment: ok, that works...thank you. The only problem remaining is this cancel button.

Comment: @Klemzy replace "# cancel button pressed" with "exit 1"

Comment: @thom, I have done that already in my script, thanks. Or should I change here to?

Comment: Yes, it will get you out of the loop and out of your program immediately.